# Sending a mail from WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs, carriage-return

I have the following code in a standard Windows 8 Javascript Store App:

```
var test = document.getElementById("testButton");
test.addEventListener("click", function () {
var mailto = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("mailto:?to=my.address@here.com" + "&subject=test" + "&body=Hello,<br>How are you?");
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(mailto);
```

The problem I have is that no matter what I do, I can't get a carriage return between `Hello,` and `How are you?`.  I've tried `\n` & `\r\n`.  What do I need to insert to get a carriage return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's a URL, you'll have to use a URL encoded character:

```
var mailto = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("mailto:?to=my.address@here.com" + "&subject=test" + "&body=Hello,%0dHow are you?");
```