# Send and retrieve emails with Winjs

Tags: javascript, windows-10, winjs, uwp

I'm developing a windows 10 universal mail app using winjs.
The layout is done but i dont know how can i send or retrive emails using javascript.
Microsoft api doesn't tell me how, and the only thing that i´ve found on stackoverflow was this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530916/sending-a-mail-from-winjs) that uses the html mailto.

Comment: A mailto link just opens the default email program (like Outlook, etc) with the To-field, subject line and email body already filled in...probably not what you want

Comment: You are correct. Using another app beats the point of making an email application.

Comment: Check out the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Email namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.aspx). The [EmailMailbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmailbox.aspx) is where incoming messages go, and you can `SendMessageAsync` to send a message.

Comment: It doenst have any code examples in Javascript, only C#, VB and others